# Determine Maximum and Minimum GPS coordinate from a list of GPS coordinates

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-maps

I have a list of GPS coordinates and I am drawing a Polyline between the Maximum and Minimum coordinate from the list. But keeping in mind the Geometry of Earth I cannot simply consider the Max and Min coordinate based on their numeric value.

Can anyone please suggest me away to determine Max and Min coordinates keeping in mind that these are from a GPS source?

Solution at Python or Android side both would do.
Thankyou!

Comment: Can't you break the steps between any given distance (between two points) and then the array with the highest length would be the farthest

Comment: I am gonna give this a try. Thankyou

Comment: How does one define "maximum" or "minimum" for two-dimensional coordinates? (GPS or anything else)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen actually I have around let's say 20 coordinates in a line  over a road. I want to display the line as a Polyline. For this purpose I needed max and min coordinates so that i can draw from one point to the other. I would welcome any other strategy to do so. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a proper answer you would first need to define what you mean by maximum and minimum coordinate. But if you define it as the coordinates having the largest distance in between them, as was suggested in the comments, then the method `computeDistanceBetween()` in the [Google Maps Android API utility library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) might help. You can use the following Java code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;  

LatLng a = ...;
LatLng b = ...;

double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(a, b);
```

You need to add the following to `dependencies {...}` in your `build.gradle (Module: app)` file:

```
compile "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4"
```